# Dart - Function Calculate difference of days

Tags: flutter, dart

i created function in flutter using dart that takes Today date and see if it equal to today or not. and u can use for a week, month..etc

here it is

```
 bool daysPassed(int timeStamp, int days) {
    if (DateTime.now()
            .difference(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timeStamp))
            .inDays >=
        days) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

so i used this function to see if a one day passed or not , if one day passed make all the variables from shared preference to zero, otherwise get the current variables

here is the logic that i made,

```
 HOME.pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    int? timeStamp = HOME.pref!.getInt('day_timestamp_values_changed');
    int? timeStamp1Week = HOME.pref!.getInt('week_timestamp');

    setState(() {
      if (timeStamp != null) {
        if (daysPassed(timeStamp, 1)) {
          // 1 means if 1 day is passed
          HOME.pref!.setDouble('currentCircleProgressValue', 0);
          HOME.pref!.setDouble('currentCircleProgressValue2', 0);
          HOME.pref!.setDouble('currentCircleProgressValue3', 0);
          HOME.pref!.setInt('iii', 0);
          if (HOME.Currentday != 0) {
            HOME.Lastday = HOME.pref!.getInt('Currentday')!;
            HOME.pref!.setInt('Currentday', 0);
          }
        } else {
          HOME.currentCircleProgressValue =
              HOME.pref!.getDouble('currentCircleProgressValue')!;
          HOME.currentCircleProgressValue2 =
              HOME.pref!.getDouble('currentCircleProgressValue2')!;
          HOME.currentCircleProgressValue3 =
              HOME.pref!.getDouble('currentCircleProgressValue3')!;
          HOME.iii = HOME.pref!.getInt('iii')!;
          HOME.Currentday = HOME.pref!.getInt('Currentday')!;
          HOME.Lastday = HOME.pref!.getInt('Lastday')!;
        }
      }
```

the problem is when i test this out the variables after still the same. nothing happens the variables not initialize to zero.

Can u please help me out ?

Thank u

Comment: Can you include code where you set `day_timestamp_values_changed`?

Comment: How have you tried debugging this?  Have you verified that `timeStamp` is not `null`?  Have you verified which branch you're executing?  What is the value of `timeStamp`?